# How to make tsfresh.extract_features work?

Tags: python-3.x

`tsfresh` is a library used for time series analyzing. I am trying to work through the [Quick Start Guide](https://tsfresh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/text/quick_start.html) in their docs but the code provided seems to not work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tsfresh import extract_features, select_features
from tsfresh.utilities.dataframe_functions import impute
from tsfresh.examples.robot_execution_failures import download_robot_execution_failures, \
    load_robot_execution_failures

download_robot_execution_failures()
timeseries, y = load_robot_execution_failures()

extracted_features = extract_features(timeseries,
                                      column_id="id",
                                      column_sort="time")
```

Output:

```
Feature Extraction:   0%|          | 0/20 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

This is where `tsfresh` gets stuck. It seems to do something in the background but does not pass 0%. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There have been a few issues mentioning this problem (see [#400](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/issues/400), [#402](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/issues/402), [#456](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/issues/456), [#490](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/issues/490)). For me, the behaviour of `extract_feature` varies amongst the example notebooks, with some giving me the same error as the one you mentioned. Following [#490](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/issues/490), turning off multiprocessing with `n_jobs=0` fixed most of my issues, e.g.:

```py
extracted_features = extract_features(timeseries,
                                      column_id="id",
                                      column_sort="time",
                                      n_jobs=0)
```

Note that:

- Although issue #490 mentions Windows, this was the case for me on MacOS 10.15
- Still the progress bar sometime remains stuck at 0% despite ongoing processing

Comment: setting n_jobs to zero helped me as well. Thanks for posting that.